# Maven + Tomcat in eclipse. Tomcat return error 405

Tags: deployment, maven-plugin, tomcat8

When I try deploy war app on tomcat using clean install tomcat7:deploy, it returns me 405 error from tomcat. My pom xml looks like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.heller.contact.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>ContactsApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>ContactsApp Maven Webapp</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>ContactsApp</finalName>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
                defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                        <path>/ContactsApp</path>
                        <!-- Set update to true to avoid exist war package can not be override 
                            error -->
                        <update>true</update>
                        <!-- Because deploy this maven project using plugin in pom so use the 
                            manager-script role user. -->
                     </configuration>

                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>


    </build>
</project>
```

I aslo added to my maven setting.xml

```
<server>
         <id>localhost</id>
         <username>admin</username>
         <password>password</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

my tomcat-users look like

```
<user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui,manager-script" />
```

Can someone give me a poit how to solve this issue? I tried everything from stackoverflow, but error is still same. Application isnt deployed on tomcat yet. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set ,,Use Tomcat installation" in overview of tomcat server propertie (doubleclick on Tomcat server in servers view) and it runs.